# Query volume of artifical blocks inside a convex hull

Tags: matlab, convex-hull

**Problem:**

I have a three-dimensional point cloud each centroid of a block representing a block. For simplicity this example is just two dimensional. 
As illustrated in the picture I want to include blocks of interest, based on a parameter. In the case here block 1,6,5,4. In order to further process them i need to find the smallest hull around them by either using an alpha shape or a convex hull. I have the coordinates of every centroid and i know the block extension so I can find easily the edge point of the blocks by:

```
    xdimension=5;
ydimension=5;
block1=[5 15 1];
block2=[5 10 0];
block3=[5 5 0];
block4=[10 5 1];
block5=[10 10 1];
block6=[10 15 1];
block7=[15 5 0];
block8=[15 10 0];
block9=[15 15 0];
blocks=[block1;block2;block3;block4;block5;block6;block7;block8;block9]

dimension=[xdimension/2 ydimension/2];
point1=[1 1].*dimension;
point2=[1 -1].*dimension;
point3=[-1 1].*dimension;
point4=[-1 -1].*dimension;
i=size(blocks,1);
point1=repmat(point1,i,1);
point2=repmat(point2,i,1);
point3=repmat(point3,i,1);
point4=repmat(point4,i,1);
edges1=[blocks(:,1:2)+point1, blocks(:,3)] ;
edges2=[blocks(:,1:2)+point2, blocks(:,3)];
edges3=[blocks(:,1:2)+point3, blocks(:,3)];
edges4=[blocks(:,1:2)+point4, blocks(:,3)];
edges=[edges1;edges2;edges3;edges4];
x=edges(edges(:,3)==1,1);
y=edges(edges(:,3)==1,2);
K=convhull(x,y)
scatter(edges(:,1), edges(:,2))
hold on
plot(x(K),y(K),'r-')
hold off
```

This produces a picture similar to the one here.

**Question**

How can I query the surface (or in my real problem the volume) that is included by the convex hull of block 2 and 3 ? I need the exact surface/ volume of every **individual** block included apart from those that I specify to be in (here with the binary indicator).
Please note that this is an example and I am looking for ideas how to do this independant of the example. I would really appreciate some help, cause I a majorly stuck here and I have no idea how to tackle it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2D I would use the [inpolygon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) function to test if a point is inside the intersection of the convex Hull and squares 2 and 3.

For 3D I didn't found an equivalent in MATLAB but the following [matlab exchange file](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull) supposed to be the solution.

An example of how to use the function inhull to find the points of the areas inside:

```
% Create a 3D cube
cubePoints = randi(5,[500,3]);

% Bounding volume
boundingVolume = zeros(8,3);
boundingVolume(1,:) = [1,3,1];
boundingVolume(2,:) = [1,3,3];
boundingVolume(3,:) = [3,3,1];
boundingVolume(4,:) = [3,3,3];
boundingVolume(5,:) = [3,1,3];
boundingVolume(6,:) = [3,1,1];
boundingVolume(7,:) = [2,1,1];
boundingVolume(8,:) = [2,1,3];

% Find points inside area
inVol = inhull(cubePoints,boundingVolume);

% Plot the point in the bounding volume in blue and the points outsode the
% bounding volume in red
scatter3(cubePoints(:,1).*inVol,cubePoints(:,2).*inVol,cubePoints(:,3).*inVol,36,'blue');
hold on
scatter3(cubePoints(:,1).*~inVol,cubePoints(:,2).*~inVol,cubePoints(:,3).*~inVol,36,'red');
```

Comment: This is a nice start, but based on the points how could you exactly get the surface/volume of the included blocks? Using the single edge points would be an approximation, but dependant on the size of the hull quite inaccurate

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are successful in finding your covex hull (using the `convhull` function), its second output variable will give you what you need (?).

```
[IDs,V] = convhull(X,Y,Z)
```

Here `V` is the volume enclosed in the convex hull of the points `(X,Y,Z)`. Bless Matlab!

Comment: I know, the thing is I want to know the exact amount included of 2 and 3 individually, not the total volume. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this method works, but if the system is large, in terms of memory consumption it has nothing to show off with:

First construct the total convex hull **in the form of a 3d binary array**. Also, each block should form a 3d binary array over the whole space, with `true` elements over the extend of the block and `false` elsewhere. (To accomplish this, check the [link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull) in [Amitay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39646354/6469393).)

Now you can calculate the share of each block from it. If you have formed everything as explained, the rest is straightforward: You can directly count the overlap of the `conv` with each `block` as follows:

```
num = numel(block);
shareofblock = zeros(num, 1);
for jj = 1:num
    overlap = block(jj) & conv;
    shareofblock(jj) = sum(overlap(:));
end
```